# Comparing two lists of strings and return boolean values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to compare two lists of strings and return boolean values. But it allways returns only True or only False.

```
stringList = ["252.007", "546.658", "252.108"]

paramValue = ["252.017", "546.658", "252.008"]

def compareList():
    return [x != stringList for x in paramValue]
   #return [x == stringList for x in paramValue]
```

The output should be a list containing the following:

```
[False, True, False]
```

I can't figure it out and I don't understand, why it returns [True, True, True] if I use != and returns [False, False, False] if i use == , can any one explain it to me?

TIA

Comment: You're comparing the string to the whole entire list, a string is never equal to a list

Comment: In some way it does. Thx a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine elements of both lists and compare them in list comprehension.

```
stringList = ["252.007", "546.658", "252.108"]
paramValue = ["252.017", "546.658", "252.008"]

def compareList(l1, l2):
    return [i==j for i, j in zip(l1, l2)]

print(compareList(stringList, paramValue))  # -> [False, True, False]
```

Comment: Please, add a little explanation also.

Comment: @Netwave Don't bother polishing this, find a duplicate, and vote to close

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

stringList = np.array(["252.007", "546.658", "252.108"])

paramValue = np.array(["252.017", "546.658", "252.008"])

res=stringList==paramValue
```

Output:

```py
[False  True False]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this

```
def comp():
       return [stringList[i]==paramValue[i] for i in range(len(paramValue))]
```